# CreateInstanceAndUnwrap locks up dll under IIEXpress

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have an ASP.NET site that does CreateInstanceAndUnwrap:

```
var setup = new AppDomainSetup
        {
            ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
            ShadowCopyDirectories = "true",
            ApplicationBase = textPipe["host"] == "web" ? Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath) : Environment.CurrentDirectory,
            ConfigurationFile = $"UnitTests/{testProject}/app.config"
        };

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("UnitTestDomain", null, setup);

        var type = typeof(TestProxy);
        var instance = (TestProxy)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            type.Assembly.FullName,
            type.FullName);
```

All works, but after I run this code under IISExpress on my dev workstation, I can no longer recompile the DLLs -- the error I get is "Unable to copy file .... because it is being used by another process." I have to stop IISExpress before recompiling. This will be definitely be a bigger issue in production, if it will be necessary to stop AppPool prior to each deployment.

Not sure why the files are locked? I am using the ShadowCopyFiles and ShadowCopyDirectories, but that doesn't seem to help.

What can I do to avoid locking files? Thank you.

Comment: did you tried with the  `CrossAppDomainDelegate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've had to deal with AppDomain, but I think maybe calling

```
AppDomain.Unload(domain)
```

at the end of the relevant request should free the assembly.  If there is a need for it to be in memory continually (if it is too expensive to reload per request), then unloading the domain probably won't work for you.